# Jest causes process to terminate unexpectedly

Tags: jestjs

We are running more than 2000 test cases with 7 workers on gitlab pipelines. Recently we decided to upgrade jest from 26 to 29. But it causes memory issue to us. For one of the fix https://github.com/jestjs/jest/pull/14015/files, I have patch packaged `jest-worker` to include this fix and specified maxWorkerIdleMemoryLimit too as `0.17`. But at the end it fails with error saying that
`A jest worker process (pid=354) was terminated by another process: signal=SIGBUS, exitCode=null. Operating system logs may contain more information on why this occurred.`

I have tried logging pending request, state of the worker, childIdleMemoryUsage and childIdleMemoryUsageLimit it produces following output before failing with this error

```
A jest worker process (pid=354) was terminated by another process: signal=SIGBUS, exitCode=null. Operating system logs may contain more information on why this occurred.

[ 2, false ] ok 231087104 17244036259 Logging necessary info here
[ 2, false ] ok 223420968 17244036259 Logging necessary info here
[ 2, false ] ok 237182144 17244036259 Logging necessary info here
[ 2, false ] ok 200207560 17244036259 Logging necessary info here
[ 2, false ] ok 200501880 17244036259 Logging necessary info here
[ 2, false ] ok 185813512 17244036259 Logging necessary info here
[ 2, false ] ok 240861664 17244036259 Logging necessary info here
[ 2, false ] ok 241815840 17244036259 Logging necessary info here
[ 2, false ] ok 221084056 17244036259 Logging necessary info here
[ 2, false ] ok 230363528 17244036259 Logging necessary info here
[ 2, false ] ok 183446384 17244036259 Logging necessary info here
[ 2, false ] ok 242024096 17244036259 Logging necessary info here
[ 2, false ] ok 175583640 17244036259 Logging necessary info here
[ 2, false ] ok 228281704 17244036259 Logging necessary info here
[ 2, false ] ok 237826080 17244036259 Logging necessary info here
```

I tried to debug this, and found out that worker does sends the `CHILD_MESSAGE_END` signal but before processEnd function gets a chance to run, _onExit function gets called. At this point request is still not null and thus this gives error. But not exactly sure why the order of sequence is as described.

Any help would be of great help